# What is the "weight" of an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I encountered a question where it asks to evaluate the "weight" of an array of numbers.  When I tried to research this one source said that the "weight" of an array of integers is the **sum of the digits of every integer** in the array. So the "weight" of `arr = [11, 13, 22, 31]` is equal to 14 because `1+1+1+3+2+2+3+1 = 14`.

Do I understand this correctly?  How would you write a function that returns the weight of such an array--in JS?  Do you split the array into a string and then simply add?

Thanks.

Comment: Sum of `(11+13+22+31) = 77` not `14`.

Comment: First, please find exactly the definition of "weight" as it was taught to you in class; then, attempt to solve the question yourself and come back with a [mcve] if you fail.

Comment: For some reason the OP is adding the digits of the numbers, not the numbers.  I don't know why you would do that.  Is 2 "heavier" than 1000000000000 ?

Comment: That is not what I asked.  I did not see it in class I just ran across this online.

Comment: @Shubham I think OP means adding the digits: 1+1 + 1+3 + 2+2 + 3+1 = 14

Comment: I can't think of a single use case where what you describe make any sense at all.

Comment: The sum of every integer in the array would be the sums of 11, 13, 22 and 31.  1, 2 and 3 are not integers in the array, they are digits of the integers in the array when expressed in decimal notation.

Comment: its just what the question ask, don't research the "weight", there is no such thing. just take it as it is in the question and write your program.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Not sure why this question got so downvoted and was closed. I am happy it was asked because I just faced a question that mentioned "weight" and I had no idea what it meant. Sometimes I think the community could be more open towards new comers. This was his first question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone is refferring - weight is the sum of the numbers, not digits.
And the function is simple:

```
var w = 0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   w = w + arr[i];
}
console.log(w);
```

But if you want to add together all the digits, you were almost correct - number to string, split it, back to integer and sum it up.

```
var w = 0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   x = arr[i].toString();
   for (var j=0; j<x.length; j++){
      ss = ss + parseInt(x.charAt(j)); //add digit by digit
   }
   w = w + ss; //add the sum of digits of 1 number to the total sum
}
console.log(w);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense.

Comment: how about accepting this answer?!